# BigQuery deduplication and partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a view in BigQuery that would allow for the following:

- Deduplication of records
- Expose _PARTITIONTIME as a column to use for filtering to allow for partition pruning

I'm aware that the suggested query to do a de-duplication is:

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(row_number)
  FROM (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY fct.KeyColumn ORDER BY fct.CreatedDatetime DESC) row_number
FROM `my-project.my_dataset.fact_table` fct)
WHERE
  row_number = 1
```

And the suggested way on how to query a partitioned table is:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `my-project.my_dataset.fact_table`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01')
  AND TIMESTAMP('2016-01-02');
```

How can I marry the two to provide a BigQuery view that is deduped and provides a column to allow the use of _PARTITIONTIME in a where clause in the view. I read about the limitations with partition pruning if using subselects etc. which is why I'm wondering whether this is possible at all.

To give you a bit of context, this view is on top of a table that is being streamed to so the dedupe has to happen on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to have the view return the latest row on a per-day basis to enable filtering on the partition time. It would be something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT day, latest_row.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME AS day,
    ARRAY_AGG(fct ORDER BY fct.CreatedDatetime DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS latest_row
  FROM `my-project.my_dataset.fact_table` AS fct
  GROUP BY day, KeyColumn
);
```

In the outer query, `latest_row.*` should also include `KeyColumn`.

Comment: That's some awesome magic there! Haven't thought about using ARRAY functions for that. Just for my understanding, does this way of deduping perform as well as the partition by statement and will this only scan the relevant partitions when applying a filter on 'day' in the outer query (or view using this query rather)?

Comment: Yes to both :) Please double check my work though. After creating the view, write a query over it that filters on the day. When you click the green check to open the validator to the bottom right of the editor, you should see the right number of bytes scanned.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I implemented a similar solution and found that while the bytes scanned were equivalent to querying the underlying table, the performance/execution time was significantly slower. Did you experience the same thing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please submit a separate question with as much detail as possible.